# Merging Variant rows in Snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant, array-merge

I have a table structure in snowflake with variant data type as shown below, you can see the a single ID is having multiple variant objects.

```
+-----+--------------------------+
| ID  | STATE_INFO               |
|-----+--------------------------|
| IND | {                        |
|     |   "population": "1000k", |
|     |   "state": "KA"          |
|     | }                        |
| IND | {                        |
|     |   "population": "2000k", |
|     |   "state": "AP"          |
|     | }                        |
| IND | {                        |
|     |   "population": "3000K", |
|     |   "state": "TN"          |
|     | }                        |
| US  | {                        |
|     |   "population": "100k",  |
|     |   "state": "Texas"       |
|     | }                        |
| US  | {                        |
|     |   "population": "200k",  |
|     |   "state": "Florida"     |
|     | }                        |
| US  | {                        |
|     |   "population": "300K",  |
|     |   "state": "Iowa"        |
|     | }                        |
+-----+--------------------------+
```

I want to combine these variant objects into a single object like below by merging the rows into one array or dictionary object

```
+-----+---------------------------+
| ID  | STATE_INFO                |
|-----+---------------------------|
| IND | [{                        |
|     |   "population": "1000k",  |
|     |   "state": "KA"           |
|     | },                        |
|     | {                         |
|     |   "population": "2000k",  |
|     |   "state": "AP"           |
|     | },                        |
|     | {                         |
|     |   "population": "3000K",  |
|     |   "state": "TN"           |
|     | }]                        |
| US  | [{                        |
|     |   "population": "100k",   |
|     |   "state": "Texas"        |
|     | },                        |
|     | {                         |
|     |   "population": "200k",   |
|     |   "state": "Florida"      |
|     | },                        |
|     | {                         |
|     |   "population": "300K",   |
|     |   "state": "Iowa"         |
|     | }]                        |
+-----+---------------------------+
```

Like in SQL terminologies, we can say like below SQL statement

```
Select id,merge(STATE_INFO) from table group by id;
```

Comment: Take a look at the `ARRAY_AGG` function.  I'm not sure whether it works on variant columns or not, but that is essentially what you are looking for.  You might need to do some casting to get it to work, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Mike said `ARRAY_AGG` function is what you need and it works on a  variant column

```
select id, array_agg(STATE_INFO) within group (order by id) STATE_INFO
from table
group by 1
order by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this CTE for data:

```
With data(id, state_info) as (
    select column1, parse_json(column2)
    from values
        ('IND', '{ "population": "1000k", "state": "KA" }'),                        
        ('IND', '{ "population": "2000k", "state": "AP" }'),                        
        ('IND', '{ "population": "3000K", "state": "TN" }'),                                
        ('US', '{ "population": "100k", "state": "Texas" }'),                         
        ('US', '{ "population": "200k", "state": "Florida" }'),                         
        ('US', '{ "population": "300K", "state": "Iowa" }')                     
)
```

This code is is almost exactly the same is demircioglu's answer, but has no ordering of the array content.

```
select id, array_agg(state_info) as stateinfo
from data
group by 1;
```

which because of the order of the input still appears ordered. But it is really random, it depends if you need the data ordered or not:

| ID | STATEINFO |
| --- | --- |
| US | [ { "population": "100k", "state": "Texas" }, { "population": "200k", "state": "Florida" }, { "population": "300K", "state": "Iowa" } ] |
| IND | [ { "population": "1000k", "state": "KA" }, { "population": "2000k", "state": "AP" }, { "population": "3000K", "state": "TN" } ] |